# How to get auto increment value in prepared command in postgresql?

Tags: c++, c, database, postgresql, libpq

I create table with this sql command:

```
create table recorddata 
( id serial, 
  name char(20),
  age int);
```

just like auto increment in mysql, I want id is auto increment in postgresql.

then, insert data in a transaction.sql command: begin, insert..., commit.

I use libpg.a to do this:

```
 first, PQexec(conn, "begin);
 then,  PQprepare(conn, "insert", "insert into recorddata (name, age) values ($1, $2)", 2, NULL)
 and,   PQexecPrepared to insert actual data
 final, PQexec(conn, "end")
```

But, how can i get id value for each time execute function PQexecPrepared ?
I tried using SELECT nextval after execute PQexecPrepared, but i can not query in a insert transaction;
and i also tried using sql command:insert into recorddata (name, age) values (&1, $2) return id, but it not work.

Comment: Use “returning” in your SQL statement, works differently but better because you can return also other values

Answer (score 1):

It should work with:
insert into recorddata (name, age) values (&1, $2) return id
Just like you do some Query SQL statement which returns a result set.

Comment: yes,  it worked.  I make a mistake.  When use PQresultStatus to check the return value of PQexecPrepared, I forget to change PGRES_COMMAND_OK to PGRES_TUPLES_OK